# Controller IP for Juju on vSphere

Tags: vsphere, juju

I'm trying deploy Juju on our VMware lab, where we currently assign VM IPs manually. However when bootstrapping the instantiated Juju controller VM gets assigned an IPv6 IP. As there is no route for this IP, juju cannot login to the controller.

Any pointers as to what configuration juju is expecting on the vSphere side, or any way to tell it which IP the controller should use? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution was to setup a DCHP server to assign IPv4 addresses. VMware IP pools don't seem to be supported.